# Increasing Volume of Specific Audio Track?

Tags: audio, ffmpeg, video

I'm a complete newbie when it comes to ffmpeg (I found out what it was 2 days ago).

I ripped a show from from a Blu-ray disk; The episodes were dual audio and had subtitles encoded in them. When I try to increase the volume of a specific audio track, the subtitles and remaining audio tracks get deleted!

How do I up the volume of one audio track without touching the other tracks as well as keep the subtitles?

Also, since there's a few episodes, is it possible to do batch conversions?

Hope to hear from you soon!

Answer (score 0):

```
ffmpeg -i input.mkv -map 0 -map -0:a:1 -filter_complex "[0:a:1]volume=3[a]" -map "[a]" -c copy -c:a:1 aac output.mkv
```

- `-map 0` selects **all** tracks (video, audio, subtitles, data, attachments) instead of using the default [selection](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg.html#Stream-selection) behavior which only selects one track per type. See [FFmpeg Wiki: Map](https://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/Map) for more info on `-map`.
- `-map -0:a:1` negative mapping that excludes input audio track #2 (notice that the track index count starts from 0). It will be included via `-filter_complex` instead.
- `-filter_complex "[0:a:1]volume=3[a]"` uses [volume filter](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-filters.html#volume) on input audio track #2. Name the output `[a]` (which is arbitrary and you can use whatever label you prefer).
- `-map "[a]"` includes audio from the volume filter.
- `-c copy` [stream copies](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg.html#Stream-copy) all streams.
- `-c:a:1 aac` overrides stream copy for output audio track #2 and uses encoder named *aac*. Because you can't filter **and** stream copy the same track: any track that is filtered must be re-encoded.